# Reading a string till a key word and replacing from there with another string in UNIX

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I am new to UNIX and am practising shell scripting. I have an application where I need string searching and replacement.

There are some lines in a file 1 and file 2. I have a search key word. If the key word is present in file 1 and file 2 then the sting after the key word in file 2 should be replaced with the string after the key word in file 1.

for example:

file 1:

```
abc def ghi jkl **unix** is the key
This file contains 3 lines and **unix** is the key
```

file 2 :

```
This is a sample sentence **unix** in the second file
This is line 2 and **unix** the new line in the second file
```

The key word is "unix".Here the string after unix in file file 1 is "is the key" so the string after the "unix" in file 2 i.e "in the second file" should be replaced with "is the key". so after the string reading and replacement the output of file should look like

file 1:

```
abc def ghi jkl **unix** is the key
This file contains 3 lines and **unix** is the key
```

file 2 :

```
This is a sample sentence **unix** is the key
This is line 2 and **unix** is the key
```

I used the following commands separately

```
 grep sed awk
```

But I am unable to figure out how can search and replacement can be combined.
can any one tell me how the above can be done.any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you plan to invoke the script?  `mangle unix file1 file2`?  How do you handle the case where `file1` contains a line `blah unix is the key` and another saying `blah blah unix is the panacea`?  What is the point of the second (and subsequent) lines in `file1`?  What happens if `file1` doesn't contain the keyword in the first line — or in any line?  Presumably, lines in `file2` that do not contain the keyword will be left untouched? The specification of the problem is, as yet, incomplete — which may be why you're having difficulty showing what you've tried.

Comment: That is just a example. consider two strings both containing a common key. the string after the keyword in the 1st one should be replaced by the string after the keyword in the 2nd one. If the key word is not present let it be left untouched.I am a newbie to unix so I am not able to figure out an approach.

Comment: The biggest question (in my mind) is "what is the purpose of the second and subsequent lines in `file1`?"  I have no idea what you want done with them.  Should they be ignored?  Should they be validated to make sure that they have the same trailing text as the first line?  And you may be a newbie, but that doesn't stop you from thinking.

Answer (score 0):

For Unix basic tools, this is easiest in Perl for me. This will demonstrate the basic methodology and quoting; you can substitute other tools if you wish.

Given these files:

```
$ cat /tmp/f1.txt
abc def ghi jkl **unix** is the key
This file contains 3 lines and **unix** is the key

$ cat /tmp/f2.txt
This is a sample sentence **unix** in the second file
This is line 2 and **unix** the new line in the second file
```

First, let's get the key:

```
$ key=$(perl -lne 'if (/^.*\*\*unix\*\*(.+)$/) {print $1; exit;} ' /tmp/f1.txt)
```

Note surrounding the call to Perl with `$( )` This executes the command (in this case, the perl one liner) and assigns the output to the variable `key`.

```
$ echo "$key"
 is the key
```

(Note `"` around `"$key"` so that the leading whitespace is printed...)

Now replace the string line-by-line in the second file:

```
$ perl -ple "s/(.*\*\*unix\*\*)(.*)/\1$key/" /tmp/f2.txt
This is a sample sentence **unix** is the key
This is line 2 and **unix** is the key
```

Note the use of `"` rather than `'` in the second invocation of Perl. That allows the use of the value of `$key` from command line substitution in Bash.

If you want to set a Bash variable with your target key:

```
$ tgt='\*\*unix\*\*'
$ key=$(perl -lne "if (/^.*$tgt(.+)/) {print \$1; exit;} " /tmp/f1.txt)
$ perl -ple "s/(.*$tgt)(.*)/\1$key/" /tmp/f2.txt
This is a sample sentence **unix** is the key
This is line 2 and **unix** is the key
```

(Note the `"` vs more usual `'` so that the values of `$tgt` and `$key` are used.)

The same method can be used with `awk` or `sed` but the regex's are a little harder I think (at least for me).

Comment: Thanks the output of file 2 is displayed. can't it be write back to file 2?

Comment: Just add the `-i` command line switch to Perl. Read [command switches in perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) for more info. Use `-ibak` to keep a backup copy.